# GCC Error: integral expression is not constant, with non-type template argument

Tags: c++, gcc

The below excerpt gives a compile error when compiling with g++ 7.2.1:

```
test.c++: In substitution of 'template<class T, int C> template<typename Base<T, B>::Type S> using Sub1 = typename Base::Sub<S> [with typename Base<T, B>::Type S = (int)(1); T = T; int C = C]':
test.c++:20:22:   required from here
test.c++:20:22: error: integral expression '(int)(1)' is not constant
     using S1 = Sub1<N>;
                      ^
test.c++:20:22: error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class T, int C> template<typename Base<T, B>::Type S> using Sub1 = typename Base::Sub<S>'
```

The excerpt, however, compiles using a variety of other compilers (clang, msvc, iar). So is this a bug in gcc or a language extension of the other compilers?

```
#define N (int)1

template<typename T, int B>
struct Base {
    using Type = T;

    template<int S>
    class Sub { };
};

template<typename T, int C>
struct Class: public Base<T, C> {
    template<typename Base<T, C>::Type S>
    using Sub1 = typename Base<T, C>::template Sub<S>;

    template<int S>
    using Sub2 = typename Base<T, C>::template Sub<S>;

    using S1 = Sub1<N>; // <-- Line 20
    using S2 = Sub2<N>;
};

using Class0 = Class< int, 0>;
int main() { }
```

The reasoning behind the `#define` is that it comes from a vendor-provided header file, namely the CMSIS headers for ARM. Also unfortunately, the defines that, for instance, ST provides in their headers for the STM32 series of microcontrollers include the cast.

From the stm32f10x.h file, found in the CMSIS support package:

```
/*!<******************  Bit definition for GPIO_IDR register  *******************/
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR0                        ((uint16_t)0x0001)            /*!< Port input data, bit 0 */
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR1                        ((uint16_t)0x0002)            /*!< Port input data, bit 1 */
#define GPIO_IDR_IDR2                        ((uint16_t)0x0004)            /*!< Port input data, bit 2 */
```

Comment: Why do you write `(int)1`?  `1`  is already an int. Incidentally that also makes the code compile.

Comment: Why do you write `#define`?

Comment: Compiles under gcc-8